# How to replace a whole `anyOf` object with a custom field?

Tags: reactjs, jsonschema, react-jsonschema-forms

I have a specific `anyOf` field in my form, and I need the whole field replaced with a [custom field](https://rjsf-team.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/docs/advanced-customization/custom-widgets-fields#custom-field-components).

I can easily replace a whole plain object with a custom field like this [[sandbox link]](https://codesandbox.io/s/uischema-test-simple-1kiell?file=/src/Test.tsx:422-700):

```js
const MyCustomField = () => "I am a custom field!";

const schema = {
  type: "object",
  title: "first",
  properties: {
    item: { type: "string", enum: ["first"], default: "first" },
    firstProp: { type: "string" }
  }
};

const uiSchema = { "ui:field": "MyCustomField" };
```

[image]

This works very well. But when I try to apply the same idea to an `anyOf` instead of a plain object, it starts acting weird. The object's title gets replaced with widget, but the `anyOf` item select is still visible, and a second instance of the widgets appears below it! [[Sandbox link]](https://codesandbox.io/s/uischema-test-plain-zquyxh?file=/src/Test.tsx)

```js
const MyCustomField = () => "I am a custom field!";

const schema = {
  $id: "xxx",
  type: "object",
  anyOf: [
    {
      type: "object",
      title: "first",
      properties: {
        item: { type: "string", enum: ["first"], default: "first" },
        firstProp: { type: "string" }
      }
    },
    {
      type: "object",
      title: "second",
      properties: {
        item: { type: "string", enum: ["second"], default: "second" },
        secondProp: { type: "string" }
      }
    }
  ]
};

const uiSchema = { "ui:field": "MyCustomField" };
```

[image]

I managed to work around it simply by nesting the `anyOf` under a new object. But I don't want to alter my schema away from the structure already used by backend just to make this work.

I tried messing with different combinations of `ui:widget`, `ui:field` and `"ui:title": "hidden"`, and combining it with the `items` keyword, but got nowhere.

Thank you very much